# SonarQube 5.3 stash plugin for pull requests

Tags: java, git, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, bitbucket-server

**I would like to create my own plugin which will be placing comments into STASH pull request based on sonar runner analyses isses**. Plugin will be writen in Java.

As example i can provide this plugin : https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash. But in SonarQube version 5.3 plugin is not receiving issues. This plugin is using PostJob (https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/stash/StashIssueReportingPostJob.java) to received issues.

In SonarQube 5.3 PostJob (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/postjob/PostJob.java) is not receiving issues (as far as i know)

I know that Stash and SonarQube have great support for REST API (which i can use to download issues from SonarQube, filter relevant issues for stash pull request, put comments into stash pull request).

But it is possible to receives issues in SonarQube 5.3 API PostJob ? It can save me some time with calling SonarQube REST API, marshaling response into objects etc.

Comment: Are you the same guy who posted the following issue on the SonarQube Stash plugin? => https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash/issues/43

Comment: OK, so instead of trying to create your own plugin, I would suggest you to help the team who develops the Stash plugin to fix this issue (if it's a real one). Forking the plugin or developing a new one won't help you in the long run, I can guarantee you.